# stop console output from unix command execution in perl

Tags: perl, unix

I am running unix commands in perl as

```
$cmd="ls -l";
$result=`$cmd`;
print $log_file $result;
```

but the output from execution is also printed on screen.
how to execute command without printing result on screen ?

Comment: No, it's not. The code you posted does not exhibit the behaviour you attribute to it. There's no way that something is sent both to the screen and to `$log_file`.

Comment: Same - I ran your code and do not get any output to the screen.

Comment: You mean, I presume, that *error messages* still get written to the screen -- please clarify your question.

Comment: Except he said "also". Those messages won't also be printed to `$log_file`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard output stream isn't printed to screen -- it's captured to `$result`.  But there is a second output stream called the standard error stream that programs can write to, and which also by default goes to the screen.  Many programs use this stream for logging, or (in the case of `ls`) for writing error messages.  To capture this in addition, use

```
$cmd = "ls -l 2>&1";
```

To discard it instead, use

```
$cmd = "ls -l 2>/dev/null";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a mistake. Try that in a shell:

```
perl -e 'my $x = `ls -l`;'
```

That doesn't produce any output.

Answer (score 0):

it happens probably because `$log_file` is somehow attached to `STDOUT`, duplicated to it, something like:

```
open(my $log_file, ">&STDOUT")
```